# How to convert exponential output to linear output

Tags: voltage, sensor, log-amplifier

I have a sensor which gives me roughly exponential output from 0 to 6 volts. How would I convert this to a linear range?

Comment: why ?  use a log amp? or a log ADC like for telecom

Comment: That gives me an answer. I'd never heard of a log amp. However, I went to a graphing tool and tried ln(ln(x)), and it was just a flatter log curve. How would I use a log amp to convert a log range into a linear range?

Comment: Well if you take ln(0) you get -infinity so you really need to define a more realistic range or be more pragmatic about what the range 0 to 6 volts means.

Comment: Anything <1 or e is negative for log and ln , so show your data.

Comment: Even with that edge case, the output itself isn't linear.

Comment: You do not need to do ln(ln(x)), but ln(e^x).

Comment: Whoops, good point. I don't know why I was using ln(x) for the input.

Comment: an ... antilog amp

Comment: poorly defined problem -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your 0-6 V range is impossible for taking the logarithm of.  The input can't go to 0, and there will be some maximum ratio of max/min input that any real system can handle.

However, there are such things as *log amps* that do what you are basically asking about.

You can make a crude log amp yourself by noting that the voltage across a PN junction is roughly the log of the current over a reasonable range.  Therefore, have your input signal control a current source.  This is applied to a diode.  The voltage across the diode is the output.

This is the basis for how log amps work inside, but there will be other compensating circuitry in a real log amp that makes the transfer function more accurate, not so dependent on temperature, etc.

Comment: I really don't need it to work at 0 volts. The sensor doesn't go to absolute 0, just close.

Comment: I saw some circuits online for log and antilog amplifiers using a diode and an opamp. I'll try something like that.

Comment: @mckryall  is it exponential to 6V or to 0V ?  There is a difference.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, yes. It doesn't really operate over 6 volts output, so I don't know what it would be over that.

Comment: let me be clear.  is it compressed near 0V or near ~6V.. dont start anything until you define the needed transfer function and tolerance

Comment: I'm not sure. The upper values go to 6 volts. I haven't gotten to look at the detailed curve of the output. I can add some filters to prepare the signal for the log amp if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkLKxZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Now you need to temperature-compensate it, and subtract out the diode voltage for those picoAmpere and nanoAmpere offsets.